Can't open photos files
My friend handed me USB drive. I put on my backup drive. Open gimp (can't load images files) I never have is problem before. I don't know I need to install a plugins or download other images viewer with add plugins.  I need help.
Frankie

What exactly happens when you try to open the files? Is gimp installed as a snap application? if so, there may be extra steps to permit it to access removable media

Being specific with details is also helpful; snap packages run confined thus don't have full access to your file-system (cannot open all locations). You've not told us what Ubuntu product or release you're using, what package of gimp you've installed (this can make a difference) or where the backup drive is mounted (which can impact what you do if if certain other unstated conditions apply). Please be specific with details.


Try opening in firefox. You can just drag and drop the image into an open firefox session, which shoupd open any image file including webhp


Please edit your question and add information which release of Ubuntu you are using.
Did you check USB drive with a file manager? Do you see any files on the drive? What are the file types?

If you are using the flatpak version, try using the --file-system option to extend to read abilities of Gimp to the directories on the USB media.
